# windows 7 text-type file icon change

Tags: windows-7, filesystems

Hey folks from the title it might sounds easy but actually its not. Registry editing of DefaultIcon inside HKCR\<*.FileExtensio> or Nirsoft utility could not do the job.

Now coming to the main thing. I want to set different icons for filetypes: txt, ini, xml. And I have set all these to be opened in Notepad++.

Any clues how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way I found for xml and text file icon dirrentiation. Now I can see default xml icon which will be opened by default in notepad++ from the below registry change.

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xmlfile\shell\open\command = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%1"